# CSS Best-Practice: Selectors or Classes / IDs?

Tags: css

What is the truly a best-practice in CSS: Using IDs and Classes or Selectors?

I have a stylesheet that is required by PHP once a form is submitted to style the results / successful-submission page and I was wondering what is a best-practise in CSS to use IDs and Classes or to use Selectors ?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by selector? There are ID and class selectors, which is what I presume you mean by using IDs and classes, but to what other selectors are you referring?

Comment: Classes and IDs are used *in* selectors, so the initial premise is misguided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The choice will depend on how your HTML is structured. If a certain style is used more than once, use classes. If a style used only for a specific tag, use IDs. Regarding the selectors, the trick is to keep them as short as possible.

Comment: Ah, okay, well if these styles are only going to applied once then I will use selectors and if multiple times I will use classes.
Is that good?

Comment: That correct. And remember: short selectors load faster. Here, there are a list of selectors: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: I love that article, thank you! Thank you for the help!

Comment: But using IDs also really increases specificity, which can cause other problems down the line. A lot also depends on the scope and scale of the projects. Large projects demand more structured and enforced naming than a brochure site. There's really more to it that this answer suggests.

Answer (score 9):

Basically classes should be used for common page objects that may or could be repeated. ID's should only be used when there is a unique element on a page that you will not have anywhere else on the page.

One way to explain this would be:

- ID = A person's Identification (ID) is unique to one person.
- Class = There are many people in a class.

### **There are no browser defaults for CLASSES and ID's**

Adding a class name or ID to an element does nothing to that element by default.

This is something that snagged me as a beginner. You are working on one site and figure out that applying a particular class name fixes a problem you are having. Then you jump over to another site with the same problem and try to fix it with that same class name thinking the class name itself has some magical property to it only to find out it didn't work.

Classes and ID's don't have any styling information to them all by themselves. They require CSS to target them and apply styling.

### **ID's have special browser functionality**

Classes have no special abilities in the browser, but ID's do have one very important trick up their sleeve. This is the "hash value" in the URL. If you have a URL like http://yourdomain.com#comments, the browser will attempt to locate the element with an ID of "comments" and will automatically scroll the page to show that element. It is important to note here that the browser will scroll whatever element it needs to in order to show that element, so if you did something special like a scrollable DIV area within your regular body, that div will be scrolled too.

This is an important reason right here why having ID's be absolutely unique is important. So your browser knows where to scroll!

### **Elements can have BOTH**

There is nothing stopping you from having both an ID and a Class on a single element. In fact, it is often a very good idea. Take for example the default markup for a WordPress comment list item:

```
<li id="comment-27299" class="item">
```

It has a class applied to it that you may want for styling all comments on the page, but it also has a unique ID value (dynamically generated by WordPress, nicely enough). This ID value is useful for direct linking. Now I can link directly do a particular comment on a particular page easily.

### **CAUTION: Be aware, Javascript does care**

JavaScript people are already probably more in tune with the differences between classes and ID's. JavaScript depends on there being only one page element with any particular, or else the commonly used `getElementById` function wouldn't be dependable. For those familiar with jQuery, you know how easy it is to add and remove classes to page elements. It is a native and built in function of jQuery. Notice how no such function exists for ID's. It is not the responsibility of JavaScript to manipulate these values, it would cause more problems than it would be worth.

### **If you don't need them, don't use them**

As you can see, classes and ID's are very important and we rely on them every day to do the styling and page manipulation that we need to do. However, you should use them judiciously and semantically.

**This means avoiding things like this:**

```
<a href="http://css-tricks.com" class="link">CSS-Tricks.com</a>
```

We already know this element is a link, it's an anchor element! No particular need here to apply a class, as we can already apply styling via its tag.

**Also avoid this:**

```
<div id="right-col">
```

ID is appropriately used here as the page will likely only have a single right column, but the name is inappropriate. Try and describe the context of the element, not where it is or what it looks like. An ID here of "sidebar" would be more appropriate.

Comment: This is a great and informative answer, but I had already chose and answer.

Comment: Oh well. At least i gave you some study material :)

Answer (score 1):

Use IDs for unique elements and use classes to apply styles more generally.

Forms should use IDs because generally they are all unique. Anything within that can use classes and you can combine the ID and class to specifically target them if need be.

HTML:

```
<form id="member-signup">
    <div class="align-left">
        <input type="text" class="large" />
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS:

```
#member-signup {
    width:600px;
    float:left
}
.align-left {
    text-align:left;
    float:left;
}
input.large {
    width:300px;
}
#member-signup input.large {
    width:450px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Classes should be used when you're styling multiple elements on a page or across your website such as all the `p` tags. ID's should only be used once per page to style general layout such as a wrapper, container etc.

Comment: if you want to style all `p` tags you would use `p { ...` instead of adding a class to each `p`

Answer (score 0):

With the semantics of HTML5, selectors are the natural way to go initially for layout based styling.
Classes are great for adding flair to elements and minimal "logic flags" for templates.
Save ids for your special elements like scrim overlays, page names and wrappers.
There should only be one instance of an id on a page, ever; which you should always keep in mind when you are writing code generated markup. Multiple ids per page can lead to some nasty bugs later on; simple bugs, but sometimes difficult to discover.